# How do I solve this using max flow?

Tags: algorithm, max-flow

C1 cities are willing to sell some goods and the other C2 cities are willing to buy some goods (each city can either sell or buy goods, but not both). Each selling city will sell its goods to one city only, and each buying city will buy goods from one city only.

Your goal is to connect the selfish cities in such a way that the amount of exchanged goods is maximized.

The hard one is the restriction that each city can sell/buy goods to/from one city only.

Comment: @duffymo I don't agree. OP does not want to know how flow can be written. I believe the question is fair - how can I apply flow to imply a given restriction in this problem. With have a specific question.

Comment: @duffymo - Your answer to Ivaylo is a bit rude - not cool.

Comment: Wow, I am speechless. I guess your comment one more time confirms what I said earlier. I guess we should stop this argument here. Thanks for your comment anyway.

Comment: @IvayloStrandjev Specific or not, it doesn't show any attempted solutions.

Comment: @Dukeling: My bad, I guess you're right. I wasn't clear as I only mentioned and asked how to solve the problem using max flow. I did use max flow, but had no idea how to apply the restriction 1-1 there :)

Comment: @Simo your answer to the comment is great. I would not have the patience to answer so kindly. I can hardly believe you are the one with less than 100 rep and answer to a person with more than 100k rep.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to solve this problem using minimum cost max flow. Add an edge between each two cities with flow 1 and cost the negation of the minimum of the selling and buying amount for this city pair. For instance if you have selling city A willing to cell X units and buying city B willing to buy Y units, then compute `Z = min(X, Y)` and add an edge between A and B with flow 1 and cost `-Z`.